# How to read parquet file from s3 bucket in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to read parquet file from s3 bucket in nifi.
to read the file I have used processor `listS3` and `fetchS3Object` and then `ExtractAttribute` processor. till there it looked fine.

the files are in `parquet.gz` file and by no mean i was able to generate the `flowfile` from them, My final purpose is to load the file in `noSql(SnowFlake)`.

`FetchParquet` works with `HDFS` which we are not used.

My next option is to use `executeScript` processor (with `python`) to read these parquet file and save them back to text.

Can somebody please suggest any work around.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you need to do with the Parquet files.

For example, if you wanted to get them to your local disk, then ListS3 -> FetchS3Object -> PutFile would work fine. This is because this scenario is just moving around bytes and doesn't really matter whether it is Parquet or not.

If you need to actually interpret the Parquet data in some way, which it sounds like you do for getting it into a database, then you need to use FetchParquet and convert from Parquet to some other format like Avro, Json, or Csv, and then send that to one of the database processors.

You can use Fetch/Put Parquet processors, or any other HDFS processors, with s3 by configuring a core-site.xml with an s3 filesystem.

http://apache-nifi-users-list.2361937.n4.nabble.com/PutParquet-with-S3-td3632.html

Comment: hi @Bryan Bende Thanks for early respond. I have tried tricking system into hadoop environment, and save core-site.xml in my home directory. and now i am having another roadblock

Comment: hi @Bryan Bende Thanks for early respond. I have tried tricking system into hadoop environment, and save core-site.xml in my home directory. and now i am having another roadblock,When running fetchprocessor I am getting the error file not found but these files are there in flowfile..
Error Log - Failed to retrieve content from .//events-1547585733674.parquet.gz for StandardFlowFileRecord. filenotfound exception

Comment: You have to specify core-site.xml in FetchParquet property Configuration Resources, putting it in your home directory does not get picked up by NiFi

Comment: Yes I have specify the core-site.xml path in 'Hadoop Configuration Resources' properties, and I am using 'JsonRecordSetWriter ' as Record Writer properties. core-site.xml is as below
<configuration> 
 <property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/opt/nifi/nifi-current/tmpfile</value>   
 </property>
 <property> 
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name> 
        <value>/opt/nifi/nifi-current/tmpfile</value> 
    </property> 
</configuration> 
 please suggest..

Comment: That shows you have specified the defaultFS as a directory on your local filesystem, so that is not going to pull from s3

Comment: You can see in the link I provided that the defaultFS would need to start with s3://

Comment: hi Bryan, yes it make sense to me now, Now i can load the fetch parquet file but getiing another error(java exception) while fetching the file - 'required binary id(UTF8) is not a group'.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that one, you would probably need to post the entire exception stacktrace as well as your parquet schema

Comment: The error I am getting are --- 
Failed to retrieve content from 1548847077946.parquet.gz for StandardFlowFileRecord [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1548968443407-5712, container=default, section=592], offs
et=534669, length=62780],offset=0,name=events-1548847077946.parquet.gz,size=62780] due to java.lang.ClassCastException: required binary id (UTF8) is not a group.. please suggest